# getting auth error while calling search date api using production environment

Tags: php, amadeus

I am able to generate access_token from production environment by given below code

```
$curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30000,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST", 
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXX&grant_type=client_credentials",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                // Set here requred headers
                "accept: */*",
                "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8",
                "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
```

after that i am trying to call

```
https://api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-dates?origin=MAD&destination=MUC
```

API. By using following code

```
$curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-dates?origin=JFK&destination=LHR&oneWay=false&nonStop=false",
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30000,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    // Set here requred headers
                    "accept: */*",
                    "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8",
                    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "Authorization: Bearer XXX",
                ),
            ));

            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            $err = curl_error($curl);

            curl_close($curl);
```

i am getting following error

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "status": 401,
            "title": "Wrong authentication credentials.",
            "code": 701,
            "source": {
                "pointer": "shopping/flight-dates"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

We had an internal configuration issue that has been fixed everything should work fine now.

2 things:
This API doesn't support airport codes you will need to replace them by city codes (LHR-> LON / JFK -> NYC), this is part of our backlog to support airport codes as well but not delivered yet. So API call should be:

> https://api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-dates?origin=NYC&destination=LON&oneWay=false&nonStop=false

The only needed header is:

```
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Bearer XXX",
    ),
```

Comment: Yes i am getting access token. I have added authorization header too. but getting same error. I am trying to access same API using Postman too and getting same error. OAuth2 api is successfull at both end.

Comment: I just checked and I don't see your account in the production environment. Did you perform the move from the test environment to the production one? It's required to use the API in production. You can find a guide here: https://github.com/amadeus4dev/developer-guides/blob/master/guides/production.md If you still face the issue can you please send an email to our support developers@amadeus.com.

Comment: I have checked my developer account is live. Even i am able to call OAuth api to get access token but when i am trying to use that access token i get auth error.

Comment: Can you send us by email (developers@amadeus.com) the email you used to create your app so I can investigate what's happening.